# How to add taxonomy filter on the query fly?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, filters, pre-get-posts

I try to add tax query on pre_get_posts hook using following code :

```
    // Add custom posts to main query (archive and home)
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_post_types_to_query' );

function add_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( (is_home() || is_category() || is_search()) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() )
    {
        // Query all posts on index and category pages
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'definition', 'video', 'data_vizualization', 'quizz', 'talk', 'question', 'study', 'bibliography' ) );

        $workspace_taxonomy_query =
                    array(array(
                        'taxonomy ' =>  'workspace',
                        'field'     =>  'slug',
                        'terms'     =>  array('particulier'),
                        'operator'  =>  'IN'
                    ));
        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $workspace_taxonomy_query;
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $workspace_taxonomy_query);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

This code give the following where clause : "0 = 1". What is wrong? Is this the good hook? How can I properly add taxonomy filter BEFORE main query is done?

Thanks in advance for answers !

Comment: +1 for using `pre_get_posts`!

Comment: There's nothing in your code that should cause `0 = 1` - I think something else is at play here.

Comment: 0 = 1 happen when the taxonomy does not exist. Check the spelling, maybe

Comment: is the taxonomy term 'particulier' right? or should it be 'particular'? Not sure if that could cause `0 = 1` but just checking.

Comment: Thx for pointing it, but I tried with many terms and it didn't work either. Furthermore, even if term not exists, it shouldn't be a problem shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax-ish error, or a spelling one. There is a space after "taxonomy" in your `tax_query` array. If that were the sum of it I'd have just posted a comment, but additionally that `$query->tax_query->queries[] = $workspace_taxonomy_query;` line is pointless. Nothing changes with or without it. Don't try to hack the array like that. Just use `$query->set( 'tax_query', $workspace_taxonomy_query);` as below (using a taxonomy and term that exists in my test environment):

```
// Add custom posts to main query (archive and home)
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_post_types_to_query' );

function add_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( (is_home() || is_category() || is_search()) && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() )
    {
        // Query all posts on index and category pages
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'definition', 'video', 'data_vizualization', 'quizz', 'talk', 'question', 'study', 'bibliography' ) );

        $workspace_taxonomy_query =
                    array(
                      array(
                        'taxonomy' =>  'post_tag',
                        'field'     =>  'slug',
                        'terms'     =>  array('test-4'),
                        'operator'  =>  'IN'
                      )
                    );
        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $workspace_taxonomy_query;

    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: You were just right, it was this space that messed up everything... Many thanks for your contribution